# SlideDeck2 Slider stopped working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

[goo.gl/8ib94](http://goo.gl/8ib94)

Slider at the top of the website is made by SlideDeck2 wordpress plugin. It stopped working suddenly. Anybody has any idea?

I thought;

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This might be doing it, but it is not. I took it out of the page, but it still did not work.

Comment: Try making a reduced test case. Getting this error isn't helping things "Object #<Object> has no method 'slidedeck'"

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean user319940...

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some Javascript errors in your page, and this is one of them.
You are using following script, before jQuery actually loads

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("a[rel*=lightbox]").colorbox({opacity:0.8});
});
```

So better move below line of code (Google-jQuery library link) from bottom to <head> section

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I disabled the lightbox plugin and moved that up but still that slider doesn't work.. :/

Comment: I fixed the problem though.. Thanks it was a good suggestion!